# Add extra filter parameters in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a method in a controller:

```
 def my_find(is_published, count)
    items = Idea.where(published: is_published)
    #......
 end
```

Sometimes I want to pass some extra filter arguments

```
 def my_find(is_published, count, some_extra_filter = nil)
    items = Idea.where(published: is_published) #.where (some_extra_filter)
    #......
 end
```

where `some_extra_filter` can be `lambda` or just an plain sql "where" `string` and it can also be `nil` or "".

So how do I **concatenate** `.where(published: is_published)` with `where (some_extra_filter)` to get what I need?

Comment: Consider using some filter gem. I suggest [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) or [meta search](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very easy using scopes:

```
def my_find
  @items = Idea.scoped
  @items = @items.where(published: is_published) unless is_published.nil?
  @items = @items.where(other: other_param) if other_params < 10
  # etc, etc
end
```

Comment: How do I convert then `@items` to the type that `Idea.all` has?

Comment: You can do `@items.all` at the end if you want, but you really don't need to. All the items will be fetched from the database when you do something like `@items.each` in the view. You shouldn't have to worry about the "type".